# NSPredicate query Subviews of UIView

Tags: iphone, nspredicate

I am trying to manage subviews in my application. I searched web and recently meet NSPredicate class. I checked examples but I stuck at somewhere here. if someone can help or correct me I ll be glad.

I got an array of subviews in UIView class. I can get this array with this command as all you know : "self.subviews". I want to get an array of subviews which x position is greatr then 2100, and code is like below:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"frame.origin.x >= 2100.0"];
NSLog(@"%d", [[self.subviews filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] count]);
```

but it gives me an error like this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSConcreteValue 0xef2a2f0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key origin.'
```

can u give a hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't work because `frame` is a `struct` and not an object and `origin` is a member of this struct. You cannot access struct members by using key-value coding.

You could try adding a category on `UIView` to add a `-(CGFloat)x` method to UIView that returns the view's x position. The predicate format would then simply be `@"x >= 2100"`.

Comment: I was going to suggest `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`, but I think a category method is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use a `UIView` category to add a `-(CGFloat) frameOriginX` method that simply returns `[self frame].origin.x`, and then use `frameOriginX` as the keyPath in the predicate.